# Why autoclosure delay evaluation and normal closure does not?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Since Apple states [An autoclosure lets you delay evaluation, because the code inside isn’t run until you call the closure.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html), why autoclosure delay evaluation and normal course does not?

I borrow the snippet with autoclosure from [John Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/using-autoclosure-when-designing-swift-apis/) to compare with/without autoclosure.

```
func assert2(_ expression: @autoclosure () -> Bool,
            _ message: @autoclosure () -> String) {
    guard isDebug else {
        return
    }

    // Inside assert we can refer to expression as a normal closure
    if !expression() {
        assertionFailure(message())
    }  
}
```

```
func assert3(_ expression: () -> Bool,
            _ message: () -> String) {
    guard isDebug else {
        return
    }

    // Inside assert we can refer to expression as a normal closure
    if !expression() {
        assertionFailure(message())
    }  
}
```

But it seems the `message()` will not be executed in both cases.

The only difference for me is I need to make closure manually:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        assert2(false, "hello2")
        assert3({return false}, {return "hello3"})
}
```

Is there some other reason that Apple and John Sundell say the autoclosure delay the execution?
For example, are normal closure being pre-evaluated because of optimization from Xcode?
Or any other reasons that closures behave in this way?

Please provide an official document if there's any which explaining this point explicitly.

Comment: You seem to be asking about "normal closures", but the code snippet you have shown shows auto closures. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was for comparison. I edited it again, I hope it's clear enough now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the distinction that the documentation is trying to draw. When the documentation says:

> An autoclosure lets you delay evaluation, because the code inside isn’t run until you call the closure.

It's not comparing `@autoclosure () -> Bool` (an "autoclosure") against `() -> Bool` (a "normal closure"). It's comparing `@autoclosure () -> Bool` to `Bool`.

The documentation is assuming that the caller stays the same, specifically in the case that the caller passes some expressions to the method. For example, for such a calling code:

```
assert(someBoolFunction(), someStringFunction())
```

Using `@autoclosure` will allow `someBookFunction` to be run at a later time (or not at all), whereas accepting a `Bool` will cause `someBoolFunction` to be called immediately, even before `assert` is called. This is because `@autoclosure` indicates that whatever expression is passed is wrapped into a closure via the magics of syntactic sugar.

Note that changing a function's parameter from `Bool` to `@autoclosure () -> Bool` is generally not a breaking change to the caller (the caller will still be able to pass expressions to the function), which is why this is a meaningful comparison.

Comment: to nitpick, but it *is* a breaking change in some edge cases. For example, `bools.reduce(true, &&)` wouldn't work because of autoclosure in `func &&(...)`, but would have worked if it didn't have the autoclosure, like with `ints.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: @NewDev Wow, I never wrote `reduce(true, &&)` and had always used `allSatisfy` instead... Didn't know it's an error until now.

Comment: haha.. it was just an illustrative example :) not necessarily a useful one. I was surprised it was an error too

Comment: Great example! I think it explains the idea of the document from Apple. Thank you for the clear explanation.